# Can one fly from Tijuana to Morelos Mexico with greencard?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, mexico

My father is very old and he's ready to go back home to Morelos but he doesn't have a lot of time to get a passport. He only has a green card and birth certificate. He has the till the end of March and it doesn't give us enough time to get emergency passport either.  What can he use instead to fly home?

Comment: Tijuana > Morelia is a domestic (within Mexico) flight. Your father is a Mexican citizen. Have you asked the airline what ID they will accept for this passenger on this flight?